# Opening a port to an application accessible outside of localhost?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, apache2

Though I have researched this all day, I still can not find a solution to this issue.

On my Ubuntu Server I am trying to run a node.js application that simply prints out "Hello World" and runs on port 3000. I want to be able to access this port not only on my localhost but also on my live website address.

Running `sudo netstat -ntlp`, I get the following:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      58639/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9418            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      585/git-daemon  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      839/dovecot     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      839/dovecot     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      792/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17862/master    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      889/ajenti-panel -d
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5314            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      947/BackupFP    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      838/nrpe        
tcp6       0      0 :::3300                 :::*                    LISTEN      26390/apache2   
tcp6       0      0 :::9418                 :::*                    LISTEN      585/git-daemon  
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      839/dovecot     
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      839/dovecot     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      26390/apache2   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      792/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      52768/index.js  
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      17862/master    
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      26390/apache2   
tcp6       0      0 :::5666                 :::*                    LISTEN      838/nrpe
```

We noticed that the port appears to open and even running

`curl exampleAddress.com:3000` results in `Hello World` but it just won't work over the internet. Using this [port checker tool](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) it seems that the port remains closed. Keep in mind that that I am just trying to access an extra port on an already up and running website that runs on port 443 (it runs on SSL this may be important).

I have ensured that the firewall is not the issue by running: `sudo ufw allow 3000` and have even tried disabling the firewall completely.

Are there any apache configurations that I am missing because port 443, 80 and 22 are open but I see no specific differences.

Comment: Where is the server hosted?

Comment: The configuration you're missing is at the router/gateway. It's not enough to open the ports in the server's firewall if it's still closed in whatever is between the server and the world at large. That's the point of the question above: If it's hosted somewhere you may need to ask the hosting service to open it for you -or- if hosting it yourself in-house it's then up to you to setup the port forwarding at your router/gateway.

Comment: @Legolas The server is hosted by 1and1 ..I will contact them and see what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I can see process index.js listening on port 3000, protocol IPv6 (tcp6) but not listening on protocol IPv4 (tcp).

You will need to check your NodeJS setup and let it listen on IPv4 too.

You can then test that with `curl -4 exampleAddress.com:3000`