# Enable Mattermost to be accessible from outside of the LAN

Tags: 16.04, networking, firewall

I installed [Mattermost](https://www.mattermost.org/) on Ubuntu 16. I configured it to work on port **8066**.

When I test it locally via curl "localhost:8066" - it works, but from "global_ip:8066" it does not work.

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled port forwarding on your router?

Comment: You need to [enable the port on the firewall (if any)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972358/opening-a-port-to-an-application-accessible-outside-of-localhost) **and** forward the port on your router (if using [NAT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972358/opening-a-port-to-an-application-accessible-outside-of-localhost), which is very probable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply enable port in iptables:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8066 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem, or is this intended as a reply to the comment?